# Why CFML keeps trying to assign rather than outputting my variable?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I'm trying to convert a list of database column names and check it inside of a query. So for example, this list:

```
<cfset permissionsLevelList = 'blnGalleryAdd,blnGalleryUpdate,blnGalleryDelete,blnGalleryMaster'>
```

This is NOT being passed on through the UI in any way.

So, then I convert it to an array and try to loop through it in my query

```
<cfset permissionsLevelArray = listToArray(permissionsLevelList)>
AND (
    <cfloop array="#permissionsLevelArray#" index="i">
        ap.#permissionsLevelArray[i]# = 1 
        <cfif i neq arrayLen(permissionsLevelArray)>OR</cfif>
    </cfloop>
)
```

But I'm getting the error cannot

```
cast [blnGalleryAdd] string to a number value
```

So, the compiler is trying to assign it as variable when I just want to output it.

Does anyone know any good workaround for this?

Comment: are you sure "cast [blnGalleryAdd] string to a number value" is from the Lucee's compiler?  Or is it from your DB?

Comment: It is from the Lucee's compilar. I pulled out of the query and tried to output it on the browser and got the same thing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-71a7.html),  tells me that when looping through an array, the `index` attribute represents the array element, not the position of that element.  Your error message reinforced that.

All you have to do is change this:

```
<cfloop array="#permissionsLevelArray#" index="i">
    ap.#permissionsLevelArray[i]# = 1
```

to this

```
<cfloop array="#permissionsLevelArray#" index="i">
    ap.#i# = 1
```

Not related to your question, but you don't really need this:

```
<cfif i neq arrayLen(permissionsLevelArray)>OR</cfif>
```

Since you are using `or` logic, you can start or finish that block with an inequality and put the word `or` inside the loop on every iteration.  Something like this:

```
and
(1 = 2
<cfloop>
or
this = that
</cfloop>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working:

```
<cfset realIndex = 1>
<cfloop array="#permissionsLevelArray#" index="i">
    ap.#i# #chr(61)# 1
    <cfif realIndex neq arrayLen(permissionsLevelArray)>OR</cfif>
    <cfset realIndex++>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: That looks fun to debug later.

Answer (score 1):

```
AND (
  <cfscript>
  permissionsLevelArray = listToArray(permissionsLevelList);
  for ( i = 1; i LTE ArrayLen( permissionsLevelArray ); i++ )
  {
    WriteOutput( (i>1?" OR ":"") & "ap." & permissionsLevelArray[i] & " = 1" ); 
  }
  </cfscript>
)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.